# Timeline of a question's views

Tags: support, feature-request, questions, statistics, views

I'd like to see how many views a particular question got, day after day, since it was posted; I'm thinking of something similar to a user's reputation timeline on his/her profile page.

Such a timeline for a question's views doesn't seem to be listed as a feature on the [site's data-explorer page](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries)...

Does TeX.SE offer this feature on some "secret page"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up posting that question on meta Stack Overflow ([there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177674/number-of-views-per-day-of-a-question-from-creation-to-the-present)), but it turned out to be a duplicate of [Is there a possibility of seeing a graph of a question's views over time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92554/is-there-a-possibility-of-seeing-a-graph-of-a-questions-views-over-time)

Short (yet definitive) answer: **no, that's not possible**.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback.